# Pypspark error :Java gateway process exited before sending its port number error in windows [SOLVED]

Tags: java, windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark on jupyter(via anaconda) in windows.Facing the below mentioned error while trying to create a SparkSession.

> ****Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number****

[Error snapshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbYYN.png)

[Error snapshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P25jJ.png)

I even tried adding **JAVA_HOME,SPARK_HOME and HADOOP_HOME** path into environment variable:

1. JAVA_HOME: C:\Java\jdk-11.0.16.1
2. SPARK_HOME:C:\Spark\spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop3.2
3. HADOOP_HOME:C:\Spark\spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop3.2

Even after this I am facing the same issue.

**PS: My pyspark version is 3.3.1 and python version is 3.8.6.**

Answer (score 0):

As per spark documentation, the string for setting master should be "local[*]" or "local[N]" for only using N cores. If you leave out the master setting, it defaults to "local[*]".

Comment: Even with local[] or local[N], I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Somehow the asterisk in local[*] was not rendered from my markdown edits. For N you should choose a number like 1 or 2 or 3, depending on how many of the available cores you want to remain unused.

Comment: Still facing the same issue. 
Is it because of the environment variable I added? or pyspark doesn't integrate well with windows?

Comment: OK my bad. Windows should not be the problem although the so-called winutils are needed. First try if spark-shell runs ok.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts, I finally figured out the issue. It was because the windows firewall had blocked java that caused this error. Once I gave the access permission the error was rectified!